# How to allow login from foreign IP on Facebook?

Tags: ruby, facebook, heroku

I have a small Ruby script which logs in from time to time into my Facebook account and do something. Now I want it to run on Heroku, but Facebook immediately blocks my account because of suspicions on unauthorized access (because Heroku's IP is different from my local).
Is it possible to calm down Facebook in that sense in order to run script on Heroku?

Comment: Scraping their pages and using any kind of automated tools to access their site is against Facebook’s ToS. If you want to interact in any way with Facebook users/data – use their API.

Comment: I'm not doing scraping nor collecting any data. I just need updated acess_token to login with it in other application. And to obtain it I need login to FB and then go to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth, maybe there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Correct, you need to go through the login dialog – in your browser, not on any remote machines.